# Can't prevent the sprite from moving out of the screen

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I want to keep my sprite just moving in the range of the screen. So I create a edge loop by `bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect`, also the collision bit mask has been set to make them collide with each other.

```
static const uint32_t kRocketCategory = 0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t kEdgeCategory = 0x1 << 6;
```

I use the pan recognizer to move the sprite and here is the current code that sets the properties of all the things.

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    // Pan gesture
    self.panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanFrom:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.panRecognizer];

    // Edge
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kEdgeCategory;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kRocketCategory;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = kRocketCategory;
    self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    self.physicsBody.restitution = 0;

    // Rocket
    SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Rocketship-v2-1"];
    texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    self.rocketSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];

    self.rocketSprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.scene.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.scene.frame)*0.3);    // 30% Y-axis
    self.rocketSprite.name = @"rocketNode";
    self.rocketSprite.xScale = 2;
    self.rocketSprite.yScale = 2;

    self.rocketSprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.rocketSprite.size];
    self.rocketSprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kRocketCategory;
    self.rocketSprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kEdgeCategory;
    self.rocketSprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = kEdgeCategory;
    self.rocketSprite.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    self.rocketSprite.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    self.rocketSprite.physicsBody.restitution = 0;

    [self addChild:self.rocketSprite];
}
```

Pan recognizer code:

```
- (void)handlePanFrom:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.selectedRocket = self.rocketSprite;
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
        translation = CGPointMake(translation.x, -translation.y);

        [self panForTranslation:translation];
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    }
}

- (void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation
{
    CGPoint position = self.selectedRocket.position;
    if ([self.selectedRocket.name isEqualToString:@"rocketNode"]) {
        self.selectedRocket.position = CGPointMake(position.x + translation.x, position.y);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when I move the sprite (rocketship) slowly, the edge will stop the sprite going out of the screen. However, when I move the sprite very quickly, the sprite will rush out the range. See the animation below. I have read some solutions to the similar problem but I still don't know what's wrong with my code. Do the edge loop and collision bit mask not enough for the situation here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is similar to what I've found when searching online, and having read what you've tried it looks like you've pretty much covered most of the more common problems (Not using SKAction, for instance).

I don't currently use a contact Bitmask to handle collisions on the side of my scene, but I do use a loop that actively checks positions.

Here's the method I use to reposition objects: (Repositions everything, you can specify it to move only the rocket.

```
-(void)repositionObjects
{
    for (CXSpriteNode *i in self.sceneObjects) // CXSpriteNode is a certain subclass
    {
        CGPoint position = i.position;
        if (position.x > self.background.size.width || position.x < 0)
        {
            CGPoint newPosition;
            if (position.x > self.background.size.width)
            {
                newPosition = CGPointMake(self.background.size.width-1, position.y);
            } else {
                newPosition = CGPointMake(1, position.y);
            }
            [i runAction:[SKAction moveTo:newPosition duration:0.0f]];
        }

        if (position.y > self.background.size.height || position.y < 0)
        {
            CGPoint newPosition;
            if (position.y > self.background.size.height)
            {
                newPosition = CGPointMake(self.background.size.height-1, 1);
            } else {
                newPosition = CGPointMake(position.x, 1);
            }
            [i runAction:[SKAction moveTo:newPosition duration:0.0f]];
        }
    }
}
```

This gets called from the SKScene loop as such:

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{ 
    [self repositionObjects];
}
```

Now, it's evidently not as elegant as your desired outcome, and I have a feeling it might still induce flickering, but I'd give it a try anyways.

Also, it might be worth trying to disable/cancel the gesture once it goes out of range momentarily to stop repeated swipes that may cause flickering.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for `repositionObjects`, it works. BTW, why using SKAction is better than directly setting sprite's position?

Comment: @WangYudong If you don't use SKAction, the sprite might not move at all. Try manually setting the position and see if it happens to you. I believe it is also recommended in the docs to move objects using SKAction as well, but I'd have to check.

Answer (score 1):

Use SpriteKit actions instead of directly modifying the position of the sprite.

What is happening is that the recognizer isn't sending updates fast enough. The sprite's bounds never intersect with the edge in any one frame.

In one update, the recognizer says that the touch is within the bounds of the edge loop. But in the next update, the touch has moved way beyond the edge loop. This leaves no frame in which the sprite's bounds intersect the edge, so no collision gets detected.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation makes sense. I use `[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(position.x + translation.x, position.y) duration:0]` instead, but problem hasn't been resolved. What kind of actions do you mean?

Comment: @WangYudong keep the duration some finite but small quantity. Make sure it's not smaller than the time period of a frame.

Comment: I make the duration be 0.02 (a little bit greater than 1/60), 0.1, 0.5, etc. Besides that the sprite becomes jerky, it still can be moved beyond the screen.

Comment: @WangYudong In that case I'd suggest using another invisible physics body with a fixed/spring joint to the rocket, and which is the one you move around.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use sprite kit in daily life, but you could for example solve it the hard way by adding something like this in your sprite's update `method`

(Pseudo code)

```
CGFloat x = clamp(self.position.x, minXValue, maxXValue);
CGFloat y = clamp(self.position.y, minYValue, maxYValue);
self.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
```